# Create scripted field on index in OpenSearch service using curl

Tags: amazon-opensearch

I have a very large index in OpenSearch service and when trying to create a new scripted field on it from the UI, the request never have chance to finish as I always get disconnected from network before it does.

So I was thinking to spin up an EC2 in the same VPC and run a curl command from machine's screen. The only thing is, I can't figure out the proper request. I tried copying the request from the browser, but that doesn't work as it uses CSRF token. I also tried using various APIs described in the docs but none of them seems to do what I want. Furthermore the documentation on scripted fields seems a bit vague.

Is there a way to create a scripted field on an existing index using curl? How would such a request look like?